# Work out the location of X given distance from 10 other map locations (in PHP)

Tags: php, google-maps, geolocation, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a variable number of locations (lat/long coordinates) on a map and an approximate distance in miles to X from each.

How can we get the most accurate lat/long location of X from this information?

I'm coding in PHP so an answer in this language would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: cast sphere/circle from each point with radius equal to the distance and compute the area overlapped by all spheres/circles or look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25928054/2521214 also this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19315299/2521214 might help

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for the links - far beyond my skill-set to have the ability to port these implementations to php w/ coordinates but I will persevere! Thank you