# Algorithm to find point within radius of many circles?

Tags: algorithm

I am given many circles of radius 1 and need to find a point (Or more likely the average of many points) that is contained within the radius of all of these circles. Is there an algorithm to do this without having to brute-force it?

Comment I added down below that specifies my problem a bit more:

"To add a bit of specificity: I am trying to find a point (or somewhere very close to it, at least within .05 unit accuracy). The only information given to me to find the point is a set of about 50 points, all of which are within a certain radius of error (in this case 1 unit) of my mystery point. Therefore, the point I am trying to find is within the radius of all of the circles given to me. I am looking for an algorithm besides brute-forcing a ton of random points until 1 fits all of the conditions. Sorry if my question is really vague, it's an abstract problem and hard to explain."

Comment: Can you give an example? What do you mean by *average of many points*? What is *contained within the radius*? Do you want a point that is inside the intersection between all circles?

Comment: @Rajesh: there is absolutely nothing wrong with this question. I have flagged your comment.

Comment: To add a bit of specificity: I am trying to find a point (or somewhere very close to it, at least within .05 unit accuracy). The only information given to me to find the point is a set of about 50 points, all of which are within a certain radius of error (in this case 1 unit) of my mystery point. Therefore, the point I am trying to find is within the radius of all of the circles given to me. I am looking for an algorithm besides brute-forcing a ton of random points until 1 fits all of the conditions. Sorry if my question is really vague, it's an abstract problem and hard to explain.

Comment: Also, the circles are not necessarily distributed evenly around the point, so an average of the centers of the circles would not be an effective estimation.

Comment: @nardavin You should edit your own question and add this information in the body of the question itself.

Comment: @MCEmperor It already has been.

Comment: take a look at this very similar problem [triangulate center point with accuracy from set of coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20817067/2521214) btw you should add sample input/output image would be ideal so we see exactly what you mean

Comment: Are you saying you have 50 points and need to find if one of those is within the radius of N circles, or do you just have the circles? The first problem is much much easier than the second.

Comment: The 2nd. I have ~50 circles and need to find a point that is contained by all of them.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is a O(n^3) time complexity solution for this problem

Where, n = number of circles

At least one of the circle-circle intersection points will be a good answer.

Find all possible intersection among all circles. Now among these intersections find the one intersection point which is inside all other circles.

Here is a simple pseudo code:

```
vector<Point> points;
vector<Circles> circs;    
for(i=0;i<circs.size();i++) {
for(j=i+1;j<circs.size();j++) {
    points.push_back(find_intersection(circs[i],circs[j]));
    //here you will find at most 2 intersections push both in this list
}

for(i=0;i<points.size();i++) {
    int cicrs_covered = 0;
    for(j=0;j<circs.size();j++) {
        if(is_point_inside_circle(points[i],circs[j])) {
            cicrs_covered++;
        }
    }
    if(cicrs_covered == circs.size()) {
        //answer is points[i]
    }
}
```